# AlarmManager cancel() does not stop my Alarm

Tags: android, widget, android-widget, alarmmanager, android-alarms

I'm creating the alarm with this code when my widget is added to screen:

```
    alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, WidgetAlarmReceiver.class);
    intent.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
    alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
    alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 60000, 60000, alarmIntent);
```

And I'm deleting the alarm using this code when no more widgets are present on the screen. **I'm calling this code on the onReceive method of the AlarmReceiver class**. Maybe that is the problem?

```
    AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent mIntent = new Intent(context, WidgetAlarmReceiver.class);
    intent.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
    PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, mIntent, 0);
    alarmMgr.cancel(alarmIntent);
```

The problem is that the alarm is still getting called each minute even doing the cancel call.

What is wrong? The startAlarm code is not getting called anymore so I don't understand why the cancel doesn't works and the alarm gets called again and again.

Comment: add: alarmIntent.cancel()

Comment: @AlessandroVerona tryed and not working

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved it, by canceling the alarm from outside the alarm `onReceive` method itself. Maybe an alarm cannot cancel itself or something.